# AWS Lambda connection to ElasticSearch / Kibana is taking over 1.5 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, elasticsearch, kibana

I have an AWS lambda which connects to ElasticSearch/Kibana using esapi. It runs a very basic query on an index - which only contains 20 small documents.
When executing the lambda after a period of no activity it takes just over 1.5 seconds to connect to ElasticSearch again. Once up and running it's then ok.
I've tried implementing Provisioned Concurrency but that didn't help.
I'm assuming it's some network/authentication issues?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is this running in VPC? Have you verified if the delay is Lambda startup itself vs. the actual connection from the now-running Lambda to ES?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. It isn't running running on VPC-not sure if that is the root of the problem. The issue does seem to be intermittent though but does look to be when the lambda (written in golang) communicates with ES.
I'll attached a log of what happens. When it hits 'Performing Search' - in this log it's showing 2820ms to complete. This is where it calls esapi.Do
I've tried with provision concurrency (but assumed it might be network related anyway) and increased the RAM to 1024mb. ES itself - 2 nodes, 2 zones & 2 masters - c5.large.elasticsearch. ES is in a different AWS account.

Comment: 2021-02-24T04:30:44.697+00:00 >....0 NewESClient-1-Creating connection to ElasticSearch
2021-02-24T04:30:44.697+00:00 >....0 NewESClient-2-estransport instance
2021-02-24T04:30:44.697+00:00 >....0 NewESClient-4-Creating ESClient
2021-02-24T04:30:44.746+00:00 >...49 NewESClient-5-Performing Search
2021-02-24T04:30:47.517+00:00 >.2820 NewESClient-7-Results
2021-02-24T04:30:47.517+00:00 >.2820 NewESClient-8-{"StatusCode":403,"..
2021-02-24T04:30:47.517+00:00 >.2820 NewESClient-9-Tidy Up